# Powershell Regex for substring over multi-line between two characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a long configuration file that I need to pull a substring from, edit some content in there, and replace the original content and save the file. I'm quite new with PowerShell but I think the last two parts I can do. The issue I'm having is with the regex match at first.

```
[SECTION1]
SETTING1=ABC
SETTING2=DEF
SETTING3=GHI
[SECTION2]
SETTING1=ABC
ANOTHERSETTING=XYZ
[SECTION3]
SOMESETTING=DFH
FINALSETTING=OWA
```

I've tested a regex on RegExr and it works OK on there, but I haven't got any joy when trying to transfer that to a PowerShell script.

```
(^\[SECTION2\](\n.+$){2})
```

What I would like to do is find "[SECTION2]", and match everything up until the next instance of "[". I currently have it matching "[SECTION2]" and two newlines, but would like to match up until the next square bracket.

I've tried a couple of commands to run the regex, but nothing seems to be bringing me anything back. For example:

```
Select-String -Path 'PATH_TO_FILE' -Pattern '(^\[SECTION2\](\n.+$){2})'
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Select-String` with a file is going to run the pattern against every line individually, but you need to match against the entire file as one big string.

There are also issues with the pattern.

Try something like this:

```
$matchObjects = Get-Content 'PATH_TO_FILE' -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)\[SECTION2\]([^\[]+)'
$contents = $matchObjects[0].Groups[1].Value
```

The `-Raw` part is what makes `Get-Content` read the entire file contents instead of line by line, and it requires PowerShell 3+.

```
\[SECTION2\]([^\[]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0L9Ha5NlfVQzyR5u)

The pattern looks for the `[SECTION2]` string, then captures a group that consists one or more characters that aren't `[`.

You can use a named capture group also:

```
$matchObjects = Get-Content 'PATH_TO_FILE' -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)\[SECTION2\](?<Content>[^\[]+)'
$contents = $matchObjects[0].Groups['Content'].Value
```

Comment: I've edited my original post. I suspect I'm not understanding the implementation quite correctly so any help is appreciated. I tried using the regex you supplied, but that didn't yield any results either.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it returns nothing. Get-Content pulls the file in so the first part is actually reading the file, but the Select-String seems to be failing to find a match. Is there any way, for example, to match everything between [SECTION2] and the opening square bracket of [SECTION3]?

Comment: @MikeWhitehead I should have looked more closely at the pattern; see my latest edit (this time I actually tried the code!)

Comment: I've just tried both suggestions above and getting "Cannot index into a null array". If I try just `Get-Content 'PATH_TO_FILE' -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)\[SECTION2\]([^\[]+)'` nothing is returned.

Comment: @MikeWhitehead sorry I'm not sure where to go from here. I used the data you provided in the question and it worked with that. Perhaps there is a difference in the file contents vs. the data you posted. Do you have any questions about what I've shown that might help you apply it to the actual file contents?

Comment: Although the above didn't work for me, it should give me a good basis on researching the problem further. Thanks for your time.